# the usage of "like" keyword in Omnet++

Tags: omnet++

I was trying to understand the usage of "like" keyword in Omnet++, what is the "like" keyword uses in Omnet++?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In NED `like` is used to [parametric submodule type](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:ned-lang:submodule-like).

Comment: The word after "like", what does it mean?

Comment: It is a NED module called `moduleinterface`, which defines what parameters, gates, submodules has to have the module that inherits from it.